# polkit pins CPU for prolonged periods of time

Tags: polkit

Whenever I start the system, `polkitd` pins 1 core at 100% during at least 4-6 hours with high disk IO and gradual increase in memory consumption. Is `polkit` in the recent Linuxae a malware?

After further investigation I found, that it uses 100% of the 1Gb LAN bandwidth at the same time; therefore, it reaches out to the mounted shared volumes on the LAN (not to the internet).

Comment: You know from your own answer that it is not malware.

Comment: No, I actually do not know that. The stopped process does not use CPU, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I stopped the process without killing it, and the system became responsive again, but I am still looking for ideas on what this pervasive process might be doing.

The only downside is that the audio mixer is not working anymore, and maybe some other things, which depend on `dbus`, so ingeniously coupled with this malware.